# Ignore and overwrite existing sheet when importing

Tags: excel, overwrite, import-from-excel, vba

The following macro imports a specific sheet called "Reviewed" from a closed workbook, imports it and renames it "Data". The macro is working fine. However, I want the macro to overwrite the existing "Data" sheet and this is where the code fails. I tried to use the `On error resume NeXT .. on error goto 0` statement. But it just added a new sheet and didn't overwrite the existing "Data" sheet.

```
Sub Import()

Dim wsmaster as workbook
Dim rd as range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    If wsmaster Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        Set wsmaster = ActiveSheet
        Set rd = wsmaster.Range("A1")
        wsmaster.Name = "Data"
        filespec = Application.GetOpenFilename()
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filespec)
        Sheets("Reviewed").Activate
        Cells.Copy rd
        wb.Close
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just overwrite the existing sheet. You need to either first delete the existing "data" sheet and then add the new one, or simply write the new data in the existing sheet (possibly first clearing out all the other data).

Version 1 where you delete the sheet could look like this:

```
Sub Import()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    If wsmaster Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("Data").Delete
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        Set wsmaster = ActiveSheet
        Set rd = wsmaster.Range("A1")
        wsmaster.Name = "Data"
        filespec = Application.GetOpenFilename()
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filespec)
        Sheets("Reviewed").Activate
        Cells.Copy rd
        wb.Close
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

The second option would be like this:

```
Sub Import()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    If wsmaster Is Nothing Then
        Set wsmaster = Worksheets("Data")
        Set rd = wsmaster.Range("A1")
        wsmaster.Cells.Clear
        filespec = Application.GetOpenFilename()
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filespec)
        Sheets("Reviewed").Activate
        Cells.Copy rd
        wb.Close
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi rohrl77. Hmm, both version don't seem to be working. I believe the second one is missing the sheet.add statement and there isn't a with-statement in the first one.

Comment: Hi Saud, you were right on the first comment about the `With` statement. I updated to take it out. It isn't needed there. The second one doesn't add a sheet bcs I assumed that the "Data" Sheet already exists in the workbook... all that the code does is clear out the cells. you can then write to that sheet leaving the name and the worksheet.

Comment: I get the following error message: "Subscript out of range" when I run the first macro. Sry, maybe I didn't explain it well, but it should both add a "Data" sheet if it doesn't already exist and overwrite it if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

rohrl77, thanks for providing me with feedback. Found the solution as:

```
Sub import_click()

    Call deletedatasheet

    Call import

    MsgBox "Data blev importeret", vbInformation

End Sub

Private Sub import()

Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
Dim rd As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    If wsMaster Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        Set wsMaster = ActiveSheet
        Set rd = wsMaster.Range("A1")
        wsMaster.Name = "Data"
        filespec = Application.GetOpenFilename()
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filespec)
        Sheets("Reviewed").Activate
        Cells.Copy rd
        wb.Close
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub

Sub deletedatasheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name = "Data" Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Saud, ok. Glad you got it. Yes it does make a difference if you first need to check if the sheet is there OR overwrite if it isn't. :- )